# display blog posts on static page

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am rather new to Wordpress and have a question. I have created my own theme, which all seems to work fine.  But, I am having one issue. I want to create my blog page (with all the posts) on a page other than my home page. So, in my theme folder, I created a page template called blog.php:

```
 <?php
  /*
  Template Name: blog  
  */
  ?>
  <?php get_header(); ?>

    <table id="about-table"  >
<tr>
    <td colspan="7">            
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php the_author(); ?>
            <?php the_time("jS F"); ?>
            <?php comments_number("0","1","%"); ?>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
   </table> 
   <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then, I created a page in wordpress called "blog" as well, in the "pages" section in the dashboard.  I then assigned its template to the above "blog" template. The problem is, though, that the code does not work as it should. Instead of showing me the titles, comments, etc of the posts, it displays some other info. On the other hand, if i just copy this:

```
   <table id="about-table"  >
<tr>
    <td colspan="7">            
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php the_author(); ?>
            <?php the_time("jS F"); ?>
            <?php comments_number("0","1","%"); ?>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
   </table>
```

to my index page, it works fine. So, how do I display all my post info on a page other than the home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you do something like this:

blog-template.php:

```
<?php/*
Template Name: Blog Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'layout-page', 'blog' );?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

layout-page-blog.php:

```
<?php 
the_post();
$title = get_the_title();
$baselink = get_permalink();
$category = get_field('category_blog'); 

if( !empty($category) ){
    $post_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page'); 
    $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

    $categoryID = get_category_id($category);

    $total = get_post_count(array($categoryID));

    $the_query = new WP_Query("posts_per_page={$post_per_page}&cat=    {$categoryID}&paged={$paged}");
?>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
    <h1 class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
    <div class="content-middle">
        <div class="node">              
            <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();  ?>
            <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <div class="content">
                <?php echo content(150); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="read-more"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a></div>                     
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <br/><br/>
            <div class="wp-paginate">
            <?php 
                wp_reset_query();

                echo paginate_links( array(
                    'base' => $baselink.'%_%',
                    'total' => ceil($total/$post_per_page),
                    'current' => $paged,
                ));

                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div> <!-- end content -->

<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

This could all be in one file, or you can use it in two pieces as I have written it.

EDIT:

Sorry I have it set to also grab the images from the post.  I think this is the functions code you need:

```
function get_images_by_cat($id){
    $limit = 1000;

    $the_query = new WP_Query("posts_per_page={$limit}&cat={$id}");
    $arr = array();
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
        $the_query->the_post();

        $title = get_the_title();
        $image_src = get_field('banner_image');
        $image_link = get_field('banner_link');

        $arr[] = array(
            "title" => $title,
            "link" => $image_link,
            "image" => $image_src,
        );
    }

    wp_reset_query();

    return $arr;    
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response.  when i run your code, though, i get this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_field()

Comment: see if this is the right code now, sorry I forgot I had a special featured image code.

Comment: thanks again for the response.  the problem seems to be with this part: $category = get_field('category_blog');  though.  i get a fatal error for a missing function get_field.  i added get_images function to my funciton.php page, just the same but the error continues

Comment: oh - yes, try creating a category "blog" and trying it again.  In this case we had other posts so we set a category for the blog page.

Comment: I'll also see if I can find a simpler loop.  This one has worked well for me in the past :)

Comment: thanks.  i tried adding a category called "blog" and adding a few posts but the same error occurs.  I just dont understand why my original code works fine in my index page but not on another template.

Comment: thank you gabearnold for your help.  i just figured it out.  not sure why my above code would work in some pages by not others, so if anyone has any insight, that would be great.  anyway, i used this code to iterate through my posts:

     <?php global $post; // required
     $args = array('category' => -9); // exclude category 9
     $custom_posts = get_posts($args);
     foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
     ...
     endforeach;
    ?>

and it seems to work fine

thanks again,
jason

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to provide you with a simpler loop as a second option.  If you use this and set Reading settings to the specific blog page this works well:

```
<?

/*

Template Name: Blog Template Example

*/

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="navigation">
    <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link(); ?></div>
    <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></div>
</div>

<?php else : ?>

<div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[image: Reading Settings]